# Body color appearing over header

Tags: html, css, document-body

I'm trying to design google play like webpage design (Mobile version). I'm using CUSTOM GRID SYSTEM (12 col 0.5% margin). The problem is that body color is appearing over header section (I think so, maybe its a different problem). I want to make it look/scroll like this:
[Example image of google play mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpGZM.png)

Here is the code:

**

> You may need to zoom to 250% or landscape max width:640px to view the
>   design.

**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
.top {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}
.nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #4caf50;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav a:hover,
.nav a:active {
  background-color: #388e38;
}
.header {
  background: url(https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg) center center fixed;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  margin: 5%;
  background: white;
}
.personal_icon {
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="max-640px.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 640px)" href="min-640px.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 640px)" href="landscape.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav>
        <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/32/1531/1531696.png" style="height:40px; float:left;">
        <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-top:0px; height:30px;">About Me</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-top:0px; height:30px;">My Projects</a>
        &nbsp;
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet or add codepen because I can't understand what you want to accomplish and what's going on

Comment: Done! Sorry! :)

Comment: Where is the header ? Which part is not working ? The snippet seems OK

Comment: I've added the header image in css (probably the image isn't loading). The body color is #eeeeee. Now the problem is that this color appears over the header section, so when I scroll the page the header remains there but the color scrolls. I want the color to remain there, just those boxes to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this. In your code you are fixing bg-image of header, therefore the body will scroll over that image, so need to fix the header instead of fixing bg-image

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding-top:70vh;
}
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
.top {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Roboto Light;
}
.nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #4caf50;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top:0;
}
.nav a:link,
.nav a:visited {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav a:hover,
.nav a:active {
  background-color: #388e38;
}
.header {background: url(https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg) center center fixed;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:40px;
  z-index:-1;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  margin: 5%;
  background: white;
}
.personal_icon {
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 640px)" href="max-640px.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 640px)" href="min-640px.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 640px)" href="landscape.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="nav">
      <nav>
        <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/32/1531/1531696.png" style="height:40px; float:left;">
        <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-top:0px; height:30px;">About Me</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="#" style="float:left; margin-top:0px; height:30px;">My Projects</a>
        &nbsp;
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_2_of_12">
        <div class="userinfo">
          <img class="personal_icon" src="large.png" srcset="large.png 800w, medium.png 500w">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It makes the whole content go down, if I use body padding-top.

Comment: Set top positions of those fixed elements, as I did in my answer

Comment: Thank you too! You both fixed the problem, but I can mark only one. As you've completely fied the problem, it it's yours.

Comment: Or you can wrap all code in a `wrapper` class and give padding to it rather than body. Otherwise if you will use this stylesheet in another page that isn't having those fixed elements,body's padding will create unnecessary sapce.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with it a bit, I think there is a problem with the header. It works if you give it `position: fixed` and `z-index: -1`. The only remaining problem is that you have to make sure that the space remains. I recommend a `<div style="height: 70%"></div>`

Comment: why not just adding a `background-color` to the header?

Comment: because the header has a background-image

Comment: Yes! Your method fixed the problem! Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Setting z-index to 1 for your nav should help.

Comment: Setting z-index values to different items, still same result. Body value: 0, nav: 1, header: 2 and container: 3.